# Android - app:drawableStartCompat show wrong color

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I use `TextView` below:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btnBack"
    style="@style/TextNormal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:text="@string/common_back"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_back" />
```

style `TextNormal`

```
<style name="TextNormal">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTextPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorTextSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_normal</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

icon_back.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="48"
    android:viewportHeight="48">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M35.556,6.828L17.901,24.484L34.994,41.733L32.176,44.55L12,24.556L15,21.556L15.085,21.643L32.728,4L35.556,6.828Z" />
</vector>
```

XML file `drawable/ic_back` has color is white. But when showing, this image display wrong color, it isn't white, `it same with color primary`, so user can't see it.

Design:
[image: image-design]

Run on device:
[image: image-run-on-device]

Do you know this bug, please help me.

Comment: Did you add `drawableTint`  to textview and Please add full code of TextView and your image view

Comment: I think the problem is in `@style/TextNormal` or image, If your Image is present in xml format then please check these attributes `fillColor` and `android:tint` in Image

Comment: The question is not in detail. Please add an image of your display view and all resources code which are you using in the textview to better understand the problem.

Comment: I updated the question. The problem is that the error does not always occur.

Comment: Actually your Back image not showing in output. Change `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` of Your `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a similar issue. In my case, the custom dialog I created displayed the icon in Activity A, but when transitioning to Activity B, the icon was no longer visible. I identified the problem as Activity B not being an AppCompatActivity. The attribute app:drawableStartCompat is processed only in AppCompatTextView, not in TextView. AppCompatActivity automatically converts TextView from the XML to AppCompatTextView.

You might want to verify this by:

1. Replacing app:drawableStartCompat with android:drawableStart and confirming whether it displays.
2. Using debug or Log printing to confirm whether the instance of  is TextView or AppCompatTextView.

If the result is that it displays with android:drawableStart and the instance of  is TextView, then this could be the reason for the issue.